# $n\geq 2 $ such that the equation $x^2-x+\hat2=\hat0$ has an unique solution in $\mathbb Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find $n\geq 2 $ such that the equation $x^2-x+\hat2=\hat0$ has an unique solution in $\mathbb Z_n$.

I've tried to solve it this way:

Let $a$ be its only solution. We see that $1-a$ is a solution too, so $a=\hat1-a \Rightarrow \hat2a=\hat1$. Now I did a thing which I'm not sure if that's true, writing $a=\hat2^{-1}$. ($\hat2$ is not invertible in $\mathbb Z_4$ for example)

$\hat2^{-2}-\hat2^{-1}+\hat2=\hat0 \ , \ \hat1-\hat2+\hat2^3=\hat0$ so $n=7.$

Can somebody tell me if this is correct?

Comment: No need for that annoying hat-symbol over the numbers. It must be clear these are elements in $\;\Bbb Z_n\;$ , not usual integers.

Comment: Another way is trying to complete the square $4^{-1}(4x^2-4x+8)=4^{-1}((2x-1)^2+7)\equiv 0\pmod{n}$ which in fields where $4$ is invertible gives $(2x-1)^2\equiv -7\pmod{n}$. But this gives $n=7$ only has sufficient condition. There is still work to prove it is the only one. So your approach is more efficient with this particular equation.

Comment: You have $\hat{2}a=\hat{1}$, so $n$ cannot be even. Hence $\hat{2}$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Well done.

Here is a simple solution along your lines.

$
\small
a^2-a+2 \equiv 0
\implies 4a^2-4a+8 \equiv 0
\implies (2a)^2-2\cdot (2a) +8 \equiv 0
\implies 1-2+8 \equiv 0
\implies 7 \equiv 0$